# Как добавить types для vue плагина?

Tags: vue.js, typescript

Пытаюсь добавить плагин для vue с использованием typescript.

В момент вызова метода моего плагина, который привязан к прототипу vue, возникает ошибка `$auth does not exist on type myComponent`.

Я описал .d.ts для плагина, правда я думаю я не совсем корректно его описал.

**Plugin**

```
import _Vue from 'vue';
import store from '@/store'
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

export default {
    install: (Vue: typeof _Vue, options?: any) => {
        const base = firebase.initializeApp(config);
        const auth = firebase.auth();
        Vue.prototype.$auth = {
            login: async (username: string, pass: string) => {
                return await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(username, pass)
            },
            logout: async () => {
                await auth.signOut()
            }
        };
        auth.onAuthStateChanged((user: any) => {
            store.commit('updateUser',{ user })
        })
    }
}
```

**myPlugin.d.ts**

```
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
    interface Vue {
        $auth: {
            login: (username: string, pass: string) => Promise<any>
        };
    }
}
```

**component**

```
export default class SignUp extends Vue {
    email: string = '';
    password: string = '';

    async onSubmit(){
        if ((this.$refs.form as any).validate()) {
            const auth = await this.$auth.login(this.email, this.password)
        }
    }
}
```